# Как запустить службу net в windows 10

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-10

При вызове утилиты net c командой view получаю ответ что служба не запущена

Answer (score 1):

Служба "Обозреватель компьютеров", которую использует net view, использует SMB 1.0, который в Windows 10 по умолчанию не установлен. Вы можете установить его, зайдя в "*Программы и компоненты*" -> "*Включение и отключение компонентов Windows*" и отметив галку "*SMB 1.0/CIFS File sharing support*". Однако, делать это не рекомендуется, ведь SMB 1.0 исключили из-за его небезопасности.

Наверное, для получения списка компьютеров следует использовать что-нибудь более современное, скажем, PowerShell ADSI:

```
powershell "([adsi]'WinNT://WORKGROUP').Children"
```

**Источники:**

[SMBv1 is not installed by default in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update and Windows Server, version 1709 and later versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows)

[How to detect, enable and disable SMBv1, SMBv2, and SMBv3 in Windows and Windows Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and)

Answer (score 0):

На уровне сетевого интерфейса за предоставление доступа к сети отвечает "Клиент для сетей".
На пользовательском уровне за предоставление перечня компьютеров (серверов) в сети отвечает служба "рабочей станции" - LanmanWorkstation.
Запуск:

```
net start lanmanworkstation
```

Не думаю, что это поможет.
Поэтому диагностируйте: смотрите статус службы, читайте журнал событий "Система" и т.д.